# Expression calculates correctly, function return NaN

Tags: r, function, nan

I have defined a function, which returns NaN (which it should not):

```
rf <- function(x,g) x^(1-g)/(1-g) 
rf(-55.45,0.9)
[1] NaN
```

But if I do the calculation by hand:

```
-55.45^(1-0.9)/(1-0.9)
[1] -14.94136
```

I cant figure out why the rf function, somehow, overflows?

EDIT: It seems the function only fails, whenever x is less than 0.

Comment: This `(-55.45)^(1-0.9)/(1-0.9)` also gives `NaN`. What you are essentially doing is `-(55.45^(1-0.9)/(1-0.9))`

Comment: I just saw the help file for ("^")... I see the error now

Answer (score 1):

That's why:

```
(-55.45)^(1-0.9)/(1-0.9)
```

The expression does:

```
55.45^(1-0.9)/(1-0.9) * (-1)
```